# Sharepoint json how can I interpolate column values into an email body

Tags: json, sharepoint

I want to generate an email from values in a Sharepoint list.

In the email body I want to use 2 columns values in one paragraph. Column 1 = 'Consultant' and Column 2 = Coaching Outcomes.

Trying to concatenate the 2 parts together like this

```
"txtContent": "We completed coaching for =[$Consultant] please see the following updates + ' ' + [$Coaching Outcomes]"
```

Using the example from https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/263378

Below is my full code. I cannot integrate the txtContext block into the email json without receiving format errors.

Email format taken from Microsoft Docs - [Create Clickable Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions)

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
                "padding-right": "8px"
            },
            "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Mail",
                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                "href": {
                    "operator": "+",
                    "operands": [
                        "mailto:",
                        "@currentField.email",
                        "?subject=Task status&body=Please see coaching completed.\r\n---\r\n",
                        "@currentField.title",
                        "\r\n",
                        {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "txtContent": "We completed coaching for =[$Consultant] please see the following updates + ' ' + [$Coaching Outcomes]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add a external {}.

```
  {
   "$schema":"https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType":"div",
   "children":[
      {
         "elmType":"span",
         "style":{
            "padding-right":"8px"
         },
         "txtContent":"@currentField.title"
      },
      {
         "elmType":"a",
         "attributes":{
            "iconName":"Mail",
            "class":"sp-field-quickActions",
            "href":{
               "operator":"+",
               "operands":[
                  "mailto:",
                  "@currentField.email",
                  "?subject=Task status&body=Please see coaching completed.\r\n---\r\n",
                        "@currentField.title",
                        "\r\n",
                  "We completed coaching for =",
                  "[$Consultant]",
                  "please see the following updates ",
                  " [$Coaching Outcomes]"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I ended up with We completed coaching for =[object Object]please see the following updates  [$Coaching Outcomes] . It didn't interpolate.